# ErlIDE Erlang tools do not support source files encoded in UTF-8

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, erlang, erlide

I have istalled ErlIDE plugin to Eclipse, and created project. In project I added new erlang module but when I want to edit it I get error

> Could not open the editor: Erlang
>   tools do not support source files
>   encoded in UTF-8

Is it bug of ErlIDE? Or erlang doesn't support UTF8?

Comment: Since the problem was solved, you should probably accept the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Erlang documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html):

> Also the source code is (for now) still expected to be written using the ISO-latin-1 character set, why Unicode characters beyond that range cannot be entered in string literals.

See [this thread](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/utf8-in-source-files-td3031128.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I set up encoding US-ASCII in Eclipse in Window->Preferences->General->Workspace, but I still get this error when I open erl file which was created in IDE. I can see otp files without any errors. What setting I need to do?

Comment: Check if the file contains non-ASCII characters or an Unicode BOM (e.g. using http://qscripts.blogspot.com/2010/04/check-if-file-contains-special-non.html).

Comment: thanks, ErlIDE added comment with date with my system locale ru_RU, I cleaned it and it works.